# automatic transaction upon expiration of time

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions

my goal is for the contract to accumulate the balance and, for example, after two days automatically send it to the wallet set there.
I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum transactions always need to be initiated by an EOA (an Ethereum wallet that maps a public address to a private key). And therefore, you would need to have a script running and initiating that smart contract call every 2 days or any other set period. You could write the script in NodeJS and you would need to use either Web3 or EthersJS to interact with the smart contract and make that call via JS. You would also need to use a scheduler lib like CronJS to run that schedule. Then, you'll need to deploy the script and have it running on a cloud server. Easiest way would be to deploy it to Heroku. If you wanted a lot more reliability, you could Dockerize the script and have it run as a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud. That way, you ensure the script is running at all times and if a running instance should fail, the cluster would spawn another instance to replace it.